# Should grammatical errors in the examples of a question be corrected?

Tags: discussion

I improved [a question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3150/at%C3%A9-or-a-onde-in-this-context), but it includes two examples which have several grammatical errors; I am not sure if they should be corrected.

Where the examples pertain to the question being asked, it's clear they should not be touched.
`Eu [vou] até os meus filhos moram` should **not** be corrected to `Eu [vou] até onde os meus filhos moram`.

But should the other parts of the examples be improved?
Or could that also be part of an answer?

## Improvement in question

> - Eu me dirijo até os meus filhos moram para levar-os ao parque.
> - Eu me dirijo a onde os meus filhos moram para levar-os ao parque.

to

> - Eu vou até os meus filhos moram para os levar ao parque.
> - Eu vou a onde os meus filhos moram para os levar ao parque.

Answer (score 5):

I think we have to use discretion, and act on a case by case basis.

In this particular case I see no problem correcting *levar-los* to *levá-los* or *os levar* because it has no bearing on the matter being asked about. But the missing *onde* in the first sentence and the choice of verb, *ir* versus *dirigir*, is a different matter, and I think we should leave them uncorrected.

The OP specifically asks about the choice between *até* and *a onde*. So answers should address this, and clarify that the real choice is between *até onde* and *aonde*. If we corrected the question, inserting *onde* in the first sentence, late answerers might miss this aspect and fail to address it.

The choice between *até onde* and *aonde* depends, in my view, on the verb that you use. So changing *me dirijo* to *vou* would affect the answers. Besides *me dirijo a* and, arguably, *me dirijo até* are not wrong. It’s just that *vou* sounds more natural. So we should leave the *me dirijo* as it is, and address the choice of verb in the answer.

So I’d say, never correct anything that has a bearing on the matter being asked about

Comment: `never correct anything that has a bearing on the matter being asked about` - but I did *not* notice that changing "dirigir" to "ir" would affect the matter being asked, until you pointed out. So I guess that this means we should never edit the examples, by principle.

Comment: I suppose we should be conservative, and in doubt let it unchanged. Or comment, and bring the issue to the OP's attention.

Comment: Here's the problem, folks. This person thought that to say drive to someone house, you used DIRIGIR. Of course, you don't. It's; ir de carro. So, if the person is **trying to learn** a language, it's best to make the whole sentence correct when it's obvious and not leave it completely unidiomatic. And now in the corrected version we have an equally awkward: ir até or a onde meus filhos moram. Francamente, quem fala assim? A pergunta foi feita encima de uma estrutura errada...

Answer (score 1):

I think so.

These corrections would preferably be edited in the question, but they could also be made as part of an answer.

NB: an answer with just these corrections would not be a useful and complete answer, if it did not address the original question.

Comment: The problem is, if you correct them late answerers may not notice them and fail to address them.

Answer (score 0):

We should never improve.

If is in a quote/example I think we should never improve because it can be intentional. First we should ask to OP in a comment if OP want to improve the sentences

If is in formulation I think we should improve, but leave a comment to the OP to confirm corrections.